# Javascript: Clear onSubmit, two fields

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Hey, help would be very much appreciated. How do I make an ifstatement so both of these fields "szValue" and "szPara" clear onSubmit? Thanks!

```
function submit() 
{     
    if (document.getElementById('szValue').value === "Enter First Value")
    {
        document.getElementById('szValue').value = "";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('szPara').value === "Enter Second Value")
    {      
        document.getElementById('szPara').value = "";
    }

    document.searchForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: You're missing a `"` before 'Enter Second Value'

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  if (document.getElementById('szPara').value === Enter Second Value"){
```

with

```
  if (document.getElementById('szPara').value === "Enter Second Value"){
```

***Edit***

Check if the case of the string is the same as in your code sample. If you want you can change the case and compare in the if statement like

```
var dVal = "Enter Second Value";

if(document.getElementById('szPara').value.toLowerCase() === dVal.toLowerCase())
{
    // write your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I actually had the quotes in the right place in the code, but when I edited it for here left it out.  You can put two consecutive if statements in there like that, though?